# truncated incorrect double (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am getting

> truncated incorrect double value error

when running

```
var post = {ip:'10.90.0.203'};
con.query("UPDATE ipaddress SET flag = 1,status = 'up' WHERE ip = ?",post);
```

this is my table structure

```
create table ipaddress(
ip varchar(15) unique not null,
flag smallint default 0,
status varchar(5) default 'down');
```

Comment: Nothing here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=runcated+incorrect+double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be done that way:

```
con.query("UPDATE ipaddress SET flag = 1,status = 'up' WHERE ip = ?",post.ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line be:

```
con.query("UPDATE ipaddress SET flag = 1,status = 'up' WHERE ip = ?",post[ip]);
```

Comment: Not `post["ip"]`  or `post.ip` ?